# Manova - standardization?

Tags: standardization, scales, manova

I would like to apply MANOVA analysis and I have 8 dependable variables. The variables measure different features in different scales - e.g, 
velocity (30-100 kmh), curve (angles 10-60) and distance (10-50 meters).
Can I apply MANOVA on these variables? Or do I need to use some kind of standardization to bring them all to the same scale?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried running an individual regression model and inspecting for any violations of assumptions (i.e. non-normal studentized residuals)?

Comment: No, can't I just look at boxes M and sphericity to ensure no violation of assumptions? 

I'm worried about the scales as I'm not sure whether the test is based only on variances or also on means. If it is based on means - there could be a problem (i.e, if I compare a scale with the values of 30-100 to lets say 1-10 there will always be a significant different unless it is standardized. That's what Im trying to ask..)

Comment: Can I ask where you know this from - that MANOVA doesn’t require DVs to be on the same scale? I am analysing a research paper that is looking at 3 motor tasks (all very similar - upper limb exercises) before and after training to see improvements They actually did 3 separate repeated measures ANOVAS and say that’s because they’re on diff scales. But I’m wondering whether MANOVA was appropriate (or if not because of the diff scales) and if it was, maybe they did ANOVAS because the variables were too correlated?

Answer (score 1):

MANOVA doesn't require the DVs to be on the same scale.